# Calculation where probability changes semi-randomly in each step

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

So say I have a situation where:
Entity A makes up 2 slots of a share, B makes up 5, C makes up 2, and D makes up 1.

By selecting a random number from 1-10 two times (rounds), 3 unique entities are picked. If an entity is picked once, then it can't be picked again. A possible chain is B-A-C and D unpicked.

A calculation for the likelihood that an entity X is selected can be simulated by doing 1-P(not X). P(not X) can be found for each round by excluding picked slots from the total share, or by randomness by rerolling numbers that land on already selected entities.

However, since the entity that is removed is randomly picked, the total P(not x) differs based which slot is picked. Is there a way one could estimate the probability of being selected in a way other than simulating trials, or by creating a massive decision tree for all possible paths of selection?

Example above:
% of selection: A: 20%, B: 50%, C: 20%, D: 10%
What's the likelihood of choosing C, if three entities are randomly selected and removed each round before it?

I feel like removing the average slots that would be removed each round instead of a discrete (and possible) number might work, but it doesn't feel right for if the differences in slot numbers between entities is very large (average of 98-slot A and 1-slot B = average of 50-slot A, 50-slot B). Is that bad intuition? Am I missing something obvious?

(It's like that stats frq problem but with the coin method every time)

Apologies if this was confusing wording.